# Getting SessionCannotBeLockedException on retrieving message

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

While performing receive operation using

```
SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);    
string sessionId = Tenant.TenantId.ToString();    
var session = await subscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(sessionId);
IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> messages = await session.PeekBatchAsync(batchcount);
```

in Topic/subscription  SessionEnabled I am getting following exception

> **"Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SessionCannotBeLockedException"**.
>
> **"ExceptionMessage": "The requested session 'sessionID' cannot be accepted. It may be locked by another receiver.**

How should I handle the above exception?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more code (we need more context around how you're setting up the session) - why are you trying to have multiple clients process messages from the same session?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I have edited my question and added the code i have used

Comment: Are you scaling out your receiver?

Comment: @SeanFeldman: No; This exception occurs when i  perform receive operation one after other.